# python play a sound/song while going to next line

Tags: python

Hello I am student of Software Developer,

Im using python to make a auto purchase bot, but when the bot can find the the buy button i would like it to play a song. I used playsound for that, but with play sound you need to have the song finished before you go to the next line. Is there a way to play a sound while going to the next line?

thank you!

Comment: Running the play sound code on a separate thread should solve your problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PedroLobito i use playsound and tried to install a library called simpleaudio but it wont install

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new thread every time you need to play a sound, here is an example:

```
from playsound import playsound
import threading

def play_sound_thread():
    playsound('your_file.mp3')

for i in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=play_sound_thread)
    thread.start()
```